# Animate selection from one button or container to other

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I am working on an app where I need to achieve a task. I am developing a custom switch button as mentioned in attached screenshot.
I want to animate like a Switch button when I click on unselected button.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this could help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XI3LFEvagBY